# Get a list of variables with a specified prefix

Tags: cmake

Is there a way to get a list of user-defined variables that have a specified prefix? For example:

```
set(vars_MyVar1 something)
set(vars_MyVar2 something)
getListOfVarsStartingWith(vars_)
```

?

Comment: The function getListOfVarsStartingWith will do what? Store all variables into a single variable?

Comment: It would create a list of variables that could then be traversed with a foreach.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The function `getListOfVarsStartingWith` can be written in the following way:

```
function (getListOfVarsStartingWith _prefix _varResult)
    get_cmake_property(_vars VARIABLES)
    string (REGEX MATCHALL "(^|;)${_prefix}[A-Za-z0-9_]*" _matchedVars "${_vars}")
    set (${_varResult} ${_matchedVars} PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction()
```

The functions uses the CMake function `string(REGEX MATCHALL` to compute all matched variable names without a loop. Here is a usage example:

```
set(vars_MyVar1 something)
set(vars_MyVar2 something)
getListOfVarsStartingWith("vars_" matchedVars)
foreach (_var IN LISTS matchedVars)
    message("${_var}=${${_var}}")
endforeach()
```

If the search should only return cache variables, use the following function:

```
function (getListOfVarsStartingWith _prefix _varResult)
    get_cmake_property(_vars CACHE_VARIABLES)
    string (REGEX MATCHALL "(^|;)${_prefix}[A-Za-z0-9_]*" _matchedVars "${_vars}")
    set (_resultVars "")
    foreach (_variable ${_matchedVars})
        get_property(_type CACHE "${_variable}" PROPERTY TYPE)
        if (NOT "${_type}" STREQUAL "STATIC") 
            list (APPEND _resultVars "${_variable}")
        endif()
    endforeach()
    set (${_varResult} ${_resultVars} PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction()
```

This function queries the `CACHE_VARIABLES` property and also makes sure that cache variables of type `STATIC`, which [are used by CMake internally](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_cache/TYPE.html), are not returned.

Comment: What I am doing with this is this: http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/SettingVariableGroups - I noticed when I applied it to my real case (where I add_library a library called MyLibrary, then have many variables called MyLibrary_Something that I want to enable/disable all at the same time) that it also catches a variable that I did not create called MyLibrary_LIB_DEPENDS. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Since your script only deals with cache variables, use `CACHE_VARIABLES` instead of `VARIABLES` upon search (see updated answer). This will return fewer false positives.

Comment: That makes sense, but it still finds this MyLibrary_LIB_DEPENDS. Here is the real code: https://github.com/daviddoria/PTXTools/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt - your function is near the bottom. I have grepped my source tree for LIB_DEPENDS (in this it is changing PTX_LIB_DEPENDS) and don't find anything, so it is certainly not something I am creating. It seems like it could be very bad that I am accidentally changing that variable? haha

Comment: The `_LIB_DEPENDS` variables are created by CMake internally to track library dependencies. Because CMake uses a special type `STATIC` for these cache variables, it is possible to filter them out. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any function to do that, but you can easily build one yourself by requesting all defined variables with `GET_CMAKE_PROPERTY` and then filtering the list with a regex.

For example:

```
SET(my_prefix_var1 "bob1")
SET(my_prefix_var2 "bob2")

# Get all variables
GET_CMAKE_PROPERTY(vars VARIABLES)

# Filter by prefix and build the "res" list
FOREACH(var ${vars})
    STRING(REGEX MATCH "^my_prefix" item ${var})
    IF(item)
        LIST(APPEND res ${var})
    ENDIF(item)
ENDFOREACH(var)
```

Comment: Hm, if I add a "message("Item: ${item}")" inside the if(item), the output is:

 Item: my_prefix

 Item: my_prefix

Shouldn't it be my_prefix_var1 and my_prefix_var2?