# How to get the value of a variable set in CMakeLists.txt?

Tags: cmake

In CMakeLists.txt, when I use SET(VARIABLE, value), I would expect that running
cmake -LA CMakeLists.txt would cause the CMakeCache.txt file generated to show the value of this variable. It doesn't. How do I view the values of set variables?

Comment: For the differences between and usage of "normal" and "cached" variables - including how to "debug" variables - see [What's the CMake syntax to set and use variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31037882/whats-the-cmake-syntax-to-set-and-use-variables). And you might find [Get a list of variables with a specified prefix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12521452/get-a-list-of-variables-with-a-specified-prefix) interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File `CMakeCache.txt` contains only **cached** variables. These ones are set using

```
set(VARIABLE value CACHE ...)
```

command flow or using some other commands(e.g. `find_path`), documentation for which explicitely says about *cache* variables.

Variables, assigned using simple

```
set(VARIABLE value)
```

are **temporary**, and exists only while CMake interpret script(CMakeLists.txt). There is no way to list such variables outside of script interpreting process.